# VSC stops seeing modules after a while

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I work in virtual environment, install some modules and write code. Sometimes when I try to start my script (CTRL + F5), I get:

> Module NotFound Error

for every installed module. Deactivate/activate virtual environment do not help, but after restart Visual Studio Code its OK for sometime. How to fix this bug?

Comment: maybe VSC has own forum and you should ask on its forum. It may have also place to send issues.

Comment: Is it valid to update or reinstall vscode?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thanks, I just had to reinstall vscode :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating or reinstalling vscode